# How to load properties files dynamically when using servlet with war file?

Tags: java, properties, jboss, resources, war

I'm using JBoss AS 7.

How can I use properties files which I download everytime(with translations) from an external folder?

I'm deploying the servlet as a .WAR file and I want to use these properties files from a random temp folder from the disk. How do I that ?

The problem is that those properties must be in the classpath.

Later edit:

```
            File file = new File(tempDir);
            java.net.URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
            ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("XXXXXX" + ReportLocale + ".properties", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

The tempDir is the location of the temp folder and the ReportLocale is changed dynamically based on the selected language. Still, this doesn't work at all and I get java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name XXXXXXX.properties, locale en_US

Comment: How is your comment helping me in any way ?

Comment: It will motivate you to search google for **IDE** and understand the difference between *IDE* and *application server*

Comment: I edited my question. Now, can you please try to be helpful instead of mocking me ?

Comment: I read your question twice and I did not understood it.Just feedback.

Comment: if you download them in a temp path, cant you use that solid path to address your file?

Comment: Edited whole question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by making a module :).

Credits to: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/219956?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating your .properties file from your .WAR deployment artifact. The .WAR file is effectively an immutable artifact and I'd be surprised if the app server allows you to change it. And even then, it's probably not a good idea.

You might also consider writing the downloaded properties to a database to better facilitate your reporting. I don't know much about your scenario, but this is an approach I would consider first.

Comment: I don't want to change the .WAR file. I want to use the properties files from outside the .WAR file.

Comment: You can load a properties file using a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). If you save the file to a path (as @Lrrr says above), then you can reload it with a ResourceBundle.

Comment: Is the file there? Can you open it with a File and log the contents? I think there's something else wrong because ResourceBundle is definitely able to read properties files. :)

Comment: an example of content : localization.~Aktualisieren~=Atualisar

Answer (score 0):

You could create a @Singleton ejb with a synchronized private method that loads the properties from a configured location

Add a method with a @Schedule on a regular basis (eg every 5 minutes) that calls the private method.

Add a @PostConstruct method that calls the private method to perform the initial loadload.

Add a method to access the properties the way the application requires.

You probably should load the properties into a new object each time before assigning the new properties object to the field. This will avoid the likelyhood that the properties object will be read by a call from the app while being loaded.

This bean can then be injected wherever you want and will serve the property values.  from the current loaded file.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where i can add the properties as soon as possible after they are downloaded.

Comment: Is 5 minutes not soon enough? You could make the schedule shorter like every minute. In this case you would probably want to keep track of the timestamp of the last file loaded and only load when the has changed.